# How to delete half the records of a table?

Tags: mysql, database, sql-delete

I have this table that holds user relations of a social network website with the following structure.

```
+--------+----------------+
| user_id| friend_user_id |
+--------+----------------+
```

And there is 2 record for every individual relationship in the table. Something like the following:

```
+--------+----------------+
| user_id| friend_user_id |
+--------+----------------+
|    1   |        2       |
|    2   |        1       |
|    4   |        7       |
|    8   |        15      |
|    7   |        4       |
|   15   |        8       |
+--------+----------------+
```

Now what I need to do is for every single relationship to be only one record present. Meaning I need to delete every second record of every relationship.

I have tried various queries to no avail. If anyone could come up with the suitable query I'll be truly grateful.

Comment: How do you define which relations should be deleted ? The last ones inserted ?

Comment: @YellowBird It doesn't really matter. As long as only one record remains for every relationship.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the relationships exist in pairs. So user A has user B as a friend and user B has user A as a friend. If I read your question right, you want to remove one of the relationships but leave the other.

Since they have different user_ids, you could delete all the rows where user_id is greater than friend_user_id. That would delete one of the relationships but keep the other.

```
delete table where user_id > friend_user_id
```

Comment: Astonishingly I think you may be right. Let me get back to you on this.

Comment: I think it worked. Thanks for the simple and effective answer. Cheers friend. :)